# How do I separate an OAuth token from my main js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth

I am making a twitch chat bot using the tmi.js module. It dawned upon me that having the OAuth token within the main js file may not be the most secure practice. How do I separate the token from the main file and include the token to my main app?

```
let opts = {
identity: {
username: <BOT USERNAME>,
password: 'oauth:' + <OAUTH TOKEN>},
channels: [
<CHANNEL NAME>]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create .env file and add it to .gitignore file.

in the .env file insert your variable like that:

```
OAUTH_TOKEN=yourToken
```

In the opts object you can call the token like that:

```
process.env.OAUTH_TOKEN
```